# Need to change osx-yosemite default keyboard-layout from Dvorak to US at login screen

Tags: keyboard-layout, login-screen, osx-yosemite

Using OSX Yosemite 10.10. Login screen defaults to Dvorak.  Also, input menu at upper right of login screen defaults to Dvorak and must use pull-down menu to locate US keyboard every time at login.  I have no need for Dvorak at all anymore.  How can I get my mac to default to US for login?

Superuser Lri posted this string in response to a similar question:

> Run
>
> ```
> sudo rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone; sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Setup\ Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Setup\ Assistant
> ```

I did a cut-and-paste and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but Terminal responded that it did not recognize the command and warned me that an improper sudo command could seriously wreck my machine.  Can anyone tell me what I did wrong, or give a step-by-step for a code-illiterate mac owner?

Answer (score 8):

Also, you can copy the plist file to your desktop and edit by Xcode than overwrite back.

```
sudo cp /Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist Desktop/
sudo chmod 0777 Desktop/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist
sudo open Desktop/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist
sudo mv Desktop/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist /Library/Preferences/
sudo chmod 0644 /Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning chown root:wheel which is required.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a while back as well. Here's what I did:

```
1. Login to your account like normal
2. Open Terminal
3. sudo cp ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist /Library/Preferences/
4. sudo chmod 644 /Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist
5. reboot, and you SHOULD be all set!
```